# Read emails in a mailbox using an admin account

Tags: powershell

I can use this script to read email in my own account. It works great.
But if I specify an admin account to read emails in another mailbox It fails on the last line of the code with **"Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection..."**

Here is my code:

```
$Userid="a4327"
$pass_secure = Get-Content "e:\hilario\cred_a910327.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Userid, $pass_secure
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll" 
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath) 
$service = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService 
$Service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials($Userid,$password)
$Sharedmail = "MessagingReports"
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($Sharedmail,$TestUrlCallback)
```

Here is the screesnhot of the running code with the error.
[image]

Comment: The error probably means that no appropriate Url could be located because your `$TestUrlCallback` predicate rejected them all. Can you post `$TestUrlCallback` as well?

Comment: Thanks Mathias. That was it. I had forgotten the $TestUrlCallback. When added this, It passed the autodiscover line. I had to add:  $TestUrlCallback = {
    param ([string] $url)
    if ($url -eq "https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml") {$true} else {$false}
}

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you could make it as an answer (and get the credit for it)

Comment: I didn't, as I was waiting for you to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MathiasR.Jessen . 
Adding the $TestUrlCallback fixed the problem.

```html
$Userid="a4327"
$Sharedmail = "MessagingReports"
$pass_secure = Get-Content "e:\hilario\cred_a910327.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Userid, $pass_secure
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll" 
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath) 
$service = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService 
$Service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials($Userid,$password)
$TestUrlCallback = {
    param ([string] $url)
    if ($url -eq "https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml") {$true} else {$false}
}
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($Sharedmail,$TestUrlCallback)
```